# Problem with Devise authentication on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I tried to use Devise 1.0.6 over Rails 2.3. I followed the installation instructions and the user can successfully sign up. However, when I use the registered user account to sign in, the password field is cleared up and nothing happened. Could anyone give me some ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Without any further detail the only thing I can advice is to follow Ryan Bates screencast on Devise maybe it can point you to the right direction (even if he uses Rails 3.0 instead of 2.3):

[Screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)

[Textual Version](http://asciicasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise)